# Why is MemberwiseClone() not virtual? in System.Object?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I found this in System.Object

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    protected object MemberwiseClone();
```

Why isn't this virtual? Wouldnt this break if i put myclass into object then call MemberwiseClone? wouldnt it called object.MemberwiseClone() in that case which has no idea about my implementation of MemberwiseClone? (I guess it can cheat with reflection but virtual would do exactly what it needs). I dont understand why is this not virtual? Also note Equals, ToString, etc are (public) virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemberwiseClone is implemented directly by the CLR, so it knows exactly what type your object is and how to make a memberwise clone. There's only one way to do it, so there's no reason to let you "customize" the behavior with some specialized logic, like Equals, ToString, etc. Another way to think about it: if you could override it, what would you do differently than the base implementation that wouldn't break the contract of the API?

Comment: i'm still a bit confused. If have `void myfunc(Object o) { o.MemberwiseClone(); }` then somone takes my dll, creates his own class and pass it in. How does the CLR know the address of the MemberwiseClone? Does it add a vtable slot for that function even tho its not marked as virtual? is there no slot and it uses reflection. It still seems funny. Good answer but the thought of the implementation seems bizarre

Comment: @acidzombie24 No, there is just "one" MemberwiseClone. The CLR knows what type each object in memory is -- that's how System.Object.GetType() works, after all. Internally, there is a pointer in each .NET object to the "method table" which can be used to figure out what type an object is.

Comment: hmm using pointer to a "method table" sounds like reflection. Ok that sounds logical. However now i wonder why MemberwiseClone is protected and not public. Feel free to answer that question. I may even ask it as its own question on SO

Comment: Internally, the CLR doesn't actually use reflection: it just creates a new object and `memcpy`'s the old object's data to the new object, making sure that various bits of bookkeeping is done so as not to break anything.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're really asking is, how does one write one own's custom Clone method, the conventional way to do this is to implement the ICloneable interface and override its Clone method. Then you can be as virtual as you like.

Comment: Thats is definitely not what i am asking

Answer (score 0):

this is what MemberwiseClone actually does:

```
protected unsafe object MemberwiseClone()
{
    object clone = RuntimeHelpers.AllocateUninitializedClone(this);
 
    // copy contents of "this" to the clone
    nuint byteCount = RuntimeHelpers.GetRawObjectDataSize(clone);
    ref byte src = ref this.GetRawData();
    ref byte dst = ref clone.GetRawData();
 
    if (RuntimeHelpers.GetMethodTable(clone)->ContainsGCPointers)
        Buffer.BulkMoveWithWriteBarrier(ref dst, ref src, byteCount);
    else
        Buffer.Memmove(ref dst, ref src, byteCount);
    return clone;
}
```

you can find it [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Object.CoreCLR.cs,1556d8bb3f97be20):